# Schedule job is not starting on Developer sandbox

Tags: apex, schedule

When I schedule a simple apex class, it gets added to the 'Schedule Jobs' list. I can even see a 'Queued' job in Apex Jobs. But the job doesn't get executed even after a considerable time has lapsed after next scheduled run time.

```
global class DSolutions_QBR_PointsSch implements Schedulable {

   Date startDate = null;

   global DSolutions_QBR_PointsSch() {

   }

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

   }
}
```

[image]

It keeps on like this forever and never get executed. What could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include the relevant code (preferable, minimal reproducible code sample) and screenshots of Scheduled Jobs queue and Apex Jobs.

Comment: Is it a repeating class? If so, it will remain "queued" until the last execution time.

Comment: it not a repeating class and just wanted to run it once. I have done this many times but seems it doesn't work now. Was there some new Apex features released in Summer '18 ?